# AS3: Change Lines Style

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, line

So I have gotten my line to draw and follow the mouse cursor around, but I think the default line style is pretty dull. So I was wondering if there was a way to change the default brush style on the line to something else, like another brush for example.

```
function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function stopDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);

    myshape.graphics.clear();
    myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0x99CC33);
}

stopDraw(null);
```

Comment: The stroke styles in the FlashPro panels are not accessible through code (if that's what you're asking?)  They can be re-created through code but it's not an easy 1 line option.

Comment: Really? That's kinda dumb would of thought they would have integrated something like that into as3. Is there a way to add like a outer glow or something to it through code

Comment: You add glows, blurs etc through filters property (it's an array that hold as many filters as you want to stack).   `myShape.filters = [new BlurFilter()];`  - Beware though, if you're animating objects with filters on them (or they are very large objects) the performance hit can be quite harsh.

Comment: Cool that works! Thank you very much if you want to answer the question with that and say they don't have a brush changing feature I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stroke styles that are found in Flash Professional are not accessible through code as an option for a graphics `lineStyle`.  They can be re-created through code but it would involve lots of tweaks to the cap styles and drawing a line for each dash (or dot) etc.

You could find some pre-made helper classes to do much of this, like this one for instance: http://andywoodruff.com/blog/drawing-dashed-lines-with-actionscript-3/

You can also add [filters](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/package-detail.html) to make your lines more interesting.

```
myShape.filters = [new BlurFilter()];
```

That would give your line a soft edge.  There are many filters built in to choose from and you can add as many as you want to the filters array property of a display object. (though beware of performance bottlenecks when getting too crazy with filters).